# Bootstrap-slider dispalying an form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a slider but fore reason only an input field is displayed.

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
>
> https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider
>
> http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

I have added:

```
bootstrap-slider.js
bootstrap-slider.css
```

What else besides an small piece of JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ex1').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});
</script>
```

And the code itself?

```
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id="ex1Slider" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
```

Please advice?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhw9n59e/)

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Yes I did @Gerard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to include jQuery, add this before you include bootstrap-slider.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You will also need to wait for jQuery before you initilize your slider

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ex1').slider({
      formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I was running jQuery.
With your edit the result has not changed.

Comment: are you able to provide all of your code? An example in jsFiddle that shows the error would be best.

Comment: I have to look into that. Won't be easy.

Comment: However you included bootstrap-slider.js in your jsFiddle it was not referenced correctly, I changed it to use this cdn https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.js and your example works fine.